# Directory in repository has wrong case

Tags: mercurial

I have a directory in my repository which has a different name/case in the repository manifest as in the file system.

(This is a Windows machine, using the hg that comes with TortoiseHg, and cygwin's bash as the command line interface.)

Here we see what it looks like on the file system:

```
$find . | grep -i cadimport.vbproj
./WIZARDS/CADIMPORT/CADIMPORT.NET/CADIMPORT.vbproj
```

And we wee that the case of the CADIMPORT.NET directory is different in the manifest:

```
$hg manifest | grep -i cadimport.vbproj
WIZARDS/CADIMPORT/CADImport.NET/CADIMPORT.vbproj
```

So, I figure that I'll just delete the directory and have mercurial bring it back, and it should come back right.

```
$rm -rf WIZARDS/CADIMPORT/CADIMPORT.NET
$hg update -C
getting changed largefiles
0 largefiles updated, 0 removed
18 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

But much to my dismay, I discover that it came back wrong, just the way that it was before:

```
$find . | grep -i cadimport.vbproj
./WIZARDS/CADIMPORT/CADIMPORT.NET/CADIMPORT.vbproj
```

What is going on here?  Why is it creating a directory with the wrong case? What can I do to get it to give me the right one?

(This case issue is causing problems when I try to create a new repository based on the code from the old one.  The difference in the case of this directory makes it impossible to import patches from the old repository into the new one.)

Comment: Interesting. Does this happen on NTFS or on FAT? Or something else, like a SMB share?